# How to reduce space between title and content in pdf_output of Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

I am using Rmarkdown to output pdf file. Here is the code:

```
---
title: |
  | This is title
  |
  | \vspace{-5truemm}Supplementary Material\vspace{-5truemm}
author: 'xxx^[Correspondence to: xxx. Email: xxx]'
geometry: margin=0.3in
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
documentclass: article
urlcolor: blue
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: yes
subparagraph: yes
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
---

\vspace{-5truemm}

# Introduction
This is introduction...

# Installation
This is installation...

## test1

### subtest1
```

And I want to know how to reduce space between the title (Supplementary Material) and content (not the body because I set toc as true).

Many thanks advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [TeXSO](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46863/169454), you can use the following package:

```latex
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
```

So, the complete example would be like this.

```
---
title: |
  | This is title
  |
  | \vspace{-5truemm}Supplementary Material\vspace{-5truemm}
author: 'xxx^[Correspondence to: xxx. Email: xxx]'
geometry: margin=0.3in
fontfamily: mathpazo
fontsize: 11pt
documentclass: article
urlcolor: blue
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: yes
subparagraph: yes
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{titlesec}
  \titlespacing{\title}{0pt}{\parskip}{-\parskip}
  \usepackage{tocloft}
  \setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-\baselineskip}
---

<!-- 
The following \vspace{} changes the spacing 
between the first section ("Introduction" here)
and the last line of the title ("Supplementary Material")
-->
\vspace{-5truemm}

# Introduction
This is introduction...

# Installation
This is installation...

## test1

### subtest1
```

Note that the `\vspace{}` before the `# Introduction` changes the spacing
between the first section (*Introduction* here)
and the last line of the title (*Supplementary Material*).
Thus, the `\vspace{}` has nothing to do with
the space between the title and TOC.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear your success! If this solution is worthy enough, don't forget to upvote, too,  haha